# Traversing drives on a computer using powershell

Tags: powershell

Trying to search all drives on a computer for .txt files with the exclusion of one directory however the results are proving inaccurate

`$drv = get-psdrive
ForEach ($drive in $drv) { gci -include *.txt -exclude excludeDir -recurse }`

Comment: Is see two flaws in your syntax: **1)** `{ gci -include *.txt -exclude excludeDir -recurse }` misses an input object, something like: `{` **$Drive** `| gci ...` **2)** If `excludeDir` is a variable that holds the "*the exclusion of one directory*", it should start with a dollar sign: `$excludeDir`

Answer (score 0):

```
cls

function isExclude($f){

    $excludes= @("C:\myExclude", "C:\`$Recycle.Bin");

    $excludes |%{
        if($f.StartsWith($_)){
            return $true;
        }
    }

    return $false
}


function isSearch($f){

    $searchs= @(".txt");

    $searchs |%{
        if($f.EndsWith($_)){
            return $true;
        }
    }

    return $false
}



try{            

    get-psdrive|% {         

         if(-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Root) -and -not $_.Root.StartsWith("\") -and -not $_.Root.StartsWith("HKEY")){
            $r = $_.Root

            Write-host -ForegroundColor black ("Checking "+$r+" drive for txt files")

            Get-ChildItem -Path $r -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |%{

                #$_.FullName                                              

                if(-not (isExclude($_.FullName)) -and (isSearch($_.FullName))){
                    write-host -ForegroundColor Gray ($_.FullName )
                }
            }
          }
     }

}catch{
    $_
}
```

Note: Using -Filter *.txt in GCI , files endswith ".txtxxx" are also found